# Chrome scroll issue for inputs with values

Tags: html, google-chrome, scroll, overflow

This [js Bin](http://jsbin.com/riqemo/edit?html,css,output) demonstrates an issue I'm seeing with Chrome. When I focus on the first input and tab through the list, focus will move to inputs that are invisible to the user without scrolling it up as it should. You'll see it when you pass item D in the list. If I remove the initial value from each input, then scrolling works as it should. It seems to me that something about the automatic selection of the previous value breaks the scrolling.

Am I doing something wrong here? It works fine in Firefox.

Also, if anyone can suggest a workaround it would be a big help.

Comment: Works fine in IE and Safari also, but not Chrome.  Weird.

Comment: I've got a hack workaround here: http://jsbin.com/befoka/edit?html,css,js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nice [hack](http://jsbin.com/befoka/edit?html,css,js), but it can be simplified:

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('focus', function(e) {
    if(this.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) {
      this.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
    }
  });
});
```

For browsers that don't support [scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded), the function won't be called.  Chrome *does* support it, so this solves the problem.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('focus', function(e) {
    this.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
  });

  $('input').first().focus();
});
```

```css
.timepoints {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.1em
}
.timepoints li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  margin-left: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timepoints">
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="A" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="B" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="C" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="D" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="E" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="F" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, much better than mine. I didn't know about scrollIntoViewIfNeeded. Seems to do exactly what I need.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem on Chrome 45 on my Chromebook.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you console.log `this.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` to see if Chromebook supports it?

Comment: I spoke too soon. It works in the jsBin when the output is popped out. But doesn't work when output is shown in one of the little strips they use. I don't need that case anyway. It's working fine at test.tarheelgameplay.org. I'll put it in production when I get back home.